# android 12 porting : Surfaceflinger deadlock

Tags: graphics, android-source, surfaceflinger, android-12

I am trying to port android 12 in my virtual setup. After running for sometime, It goes into some deadlock. On further debugging I found that 'surfaceflinger' process is actually stuck. Using ps -e command I found that It is stuck on "futex_wait_queue_me".

Please find the details below:
Android AOSP : android-12.0.0_r2

OpenGL ES : Google swiftshader

Kernel Version: android12-5.10

Gralloc allocation: using ashmem

Any idea on this ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Surfaceflinger is taking 100% CPU resource and is stuck on "futex_wait_queue_me". Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: In my case, Android was using SKIAGL as a default renderer. If you are using swiftshader, then you should set renderer as gles viz. setprop debug.renderengine.backend "gles"